# How do I get data from a Java REST service with angular.js

Tags: angularjs, jakarta-ee

I'm using the default JEE7 REST application on Netbeans.  The REST method that I'm trying to call is:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public Customer find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    return super.find(id);
}
```

I can successfully get a list of all customers.  However, when I get the customer ID on the client side with angular, it generates this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/mavenproject2/customers?0=1
```

(when I passed the ID of 1)
The addition of "?" and the index added "0=" makes the call fail.

```
http://localhost:8080/mavenproject2/customers/1 works
```

My service looks like this:

```
   customerServices.factory('customerById', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/mavenproject2/customers/:id', {id: "@id"}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
})
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
.controller('customerDetailsController', function ($scope, $routeParams, customerById) {
    $scope.customer = customerById.query($routeParams.customerId);

});
```

Assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the argument as object, having the field(s) specified with the `@`. For your case:

```
$scope.customer = customerById.query({ id: $routeParams.customerId });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.fetchData = function() {
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/mavenproject2/customers/',
        params : {id : theIdFromYourCode}
    }).success(function(data) {
        // do something
    }).error(function(data, status) {
        // do something if error
    });
};
```

Note that you will have to include the **$http** module.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I tried to stay away from $http as I knew that angular would be able to talk to Java (the angular api just had to work ;)